# Problem with a MySQL query with JOIN relation and COUNT

Tags: mysql

I have a table where I store the relations of users with a projects. The projects can be grouped with a reftecid and I need to obtain the relation of users - duration with a simple query.

Here is my table `rel_user_proj`:

```
userid / projectid / role / duration (default NULL) / inactuserid (default NULL) / inactstamp (default NULL)
```

Then I'm trying this:

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS total, duration
FROM projects p
JOIN rel_user_proj rup ON p.projectid = rup.projectid
WHERE p.reftecid=26
AND rup.duration IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY duration
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

What I finally need is a list like:

- total: 1, duration: 3
- total: 3, duration: 12
- total: 2, duration: 1

In my current query, what I get is:

- total: 58, duration: 1 <- NOT VALID
- total: 1, duration: 9 <- VALID

The only projectid with reftecid=26 is 2010202, if I do:

```
SELECT * FROM `rel_user_proj` WHERE projectid=2010202
```

I get a UNIQUE row userid=49 with the correct duration. I do not understand where the 58 others are comming.

Can anybody help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: try to remove the count and the group by and see hown many rows you have before the grouping, then add some columns in the select to see what are these rows

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS total, duration
FROM projects p
JOIN rel_user_proj rup ON p.projectid = rup.projectid
WHERE p.reftecid=26
AND rup.duration IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY reftecid
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I am not entirely sure how the duration plays a role in the above but if you need the sum of all the durations then you can do something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS total, sum(duration) AS total_duration
FROM projects p
JOIN rel_user_proj rup ON p.projectid = rup.projectid
WHERE p.reftecid=26
AND rup.duration IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY reftecid
LIMIT 0 , 30
```